# AngularJS applications imply single page applications?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

So I just spent the past 5 hours reading up on Angular JS. It seems like a lot of people are heavily associating this framework to single page applications especially when accommodated with a back-end MVC framework with nice API usage like Ruby on Rails or Laravel.

I have 2 main questions that have been boggling me:

- How do you initialize such apps considering that the content is
  dynamic in nature. When using something like RoR/Laravel, I'd prepare
  the HTML with the dynamic data at the back-end and then serve the
  initial pages. It seems like most people using Angular serve up a
  basic skeleton of the HTML and then do a round trip to web server
  again for some data. Is this really how its done? if not, please
  suggest a the right way.
- Secondly, I dont think I am about to embark on a project with a
  single paged application in mind. Does that mean it would be overkill
  to use AngularJS for my project. Does anyone have a use case that
  they think is appropriate that would require AngularJS with non
  single page application that jQuery cant handle easily?

Comment: As for first question - It's basically a front end MVC. No need for back end MVC. You load templates and let data models populate those templates. Your assessment is on target. As for second question it really depends on what page will do...no simple answer there although generally will write less code using angular even though jquery mantra is "write less - do more" angular's would be "write even less-do even more"

Comment: The additional round trip isn't quite as bad if your "basic skeleton" is static and cached by proxies along the way. With proper headers set, most of your app will only ever be transferred once to the client..

Comment: your question is a bit unfocused and feels a bit like you are asking opinions which *technically* makes it not a good fit for this site, but I will toss a few ideas here anyway.

Comment: Angular does not aim to do the same things that jQuery does (in fact, it uses either jQuery or jQlite within itself).  Rather than focusing on DOM behaviors, Angular focuses on the data that is being represented.  While some things are more trivial in jQuery and some things are more complex in jQuery, this isn't the metric to compare.  If your application is data centric, Angular is designed to help you manage and represent it.  If your application is primarily about making the UI do cool things, then that's jQuery.  And you *can* use them together (though you shouldn't need to, usually).

Comment: From a server perspective, Angular is all about making the user experience more responsive by using asynchronous requests for data.  You don't *need* to use angular as a SPA, but by taking advantage of it's SPA capabilities, your UI can do more with less data transfer, which is especially good for mobile devices.  Of course, if you aren't working with large amounts of data, this may not be important either.

Comment: @Claies Thank you for the in depth answer. Very insightful. Please put it down so that I may tick it. Much appreciated

Comment: I *purposely* added my thoughts as comments rather than an official answer, because as I said, I feel it's really a matter of opinion rather than fact.  However, I'm glad that my insights give you a better idea of the pros and cons of the framework.

Comment: Yes it has, thank you for sharing.Quite honestly, I don't think there is a definitive answer to this question.